# How to programmatically retrieve msmq statistical counters?

Tags: msmq

I have a windows servive installed thatis a MSMQ Listener. I need to get the MSMQ statistical counters programmatically for non transactional response quque.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have look at the **Performance Counters**.

I did not use the Performance Counters for MSMQ yet, but I did use them for other things like CPU load. It is not too hard to get into.

(From the first linked article below)

> MSMQ performance counters were part of MSMQ since day 1. [...]
>   Performance counters are easy to approach
>   through WMI interface, and many monitoring tools interface to them
>   anyway. However, when using perf. counters you don’t get the most
>   up-to-date data and they are not always accurate, especially when
>   looking at remote machine.

Here are a few articles to get you started:

- [Counting the number of messages in a queue](http://yoelarnon.wordpress.com/2004/12/07/counting-the-number-of-messages-in-a-queue/)
- [Monitoring Message Queuing performance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736883%28WS.10%29.aspx)
- [MSMQ Adapter Performance Counters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577997.aspx)

The first article also mentions the **MSMQ Admin API**, which I have not yet used. So I personal cannot give any recommendations about it:

> MSMQ Admin APIs were introduced with NT4 SP6a (so you probably have
>   them…) however a COM interface to them was not supplied until MSMQ 3.0
>   (WXP or W2003). If you have WinNT or Win2K, you will have to use the C
>   APIs. On the other hand, the results from MSMQ Admin APIs are more
>   current and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Code from which you get count of Message queue you just need to pass name of queue for which you want msmq count.

```
    //Here QueueName is Pass from Calling Function for which you want count of messages.
    Public MessageCount(string QueueName)
    {           
        int messageCount = 0;
        try
        {
            string fullyQualifiedQueueName = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", Environment.MachineName, QueueName);
            PerformanceCounterCategory category = new PerformanceCounterCategory("MSMQ Queue");
            PerformanceCounter cntr = new PerformanceCounter("MSMQ Queue", "Messages in Queue");
            if (category.InstanceExists(fullyQualifiedQueueName.ToLower()))
            {
                cntr.InstanceName = fullyQualifiedQueueName.ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                messageCount = (int)cntr.NextValue();
            }
            ((IDisposable)cntr).Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("Message Count is {0}", messageCount.Tostring());
        }
        Catch(Exeption Ex)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Error : {0}",Ex.Message);
        }
    }
```